# How can I add static text to my MSCRM form?

Tags: forms, dynamics-crm, xrm

I need to add static text on my form (can't use the xrm notification option) under specific terms I need to show and hide that text but I can't hold it in a field.

First I thought to use an Image with my text on the form, is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Web resource is the only supported way for user static content.

Answer (score 4):

Like said in comments, HTML web resource is the way to go. You can embed the HTML in a form section/tab and hide them using conditional scripting in form load.

[Reference](https://powerobjects.com/dynamics-365/html-web-resources-in-dynamics-365/)

> [image]

Comment: the "Reference" link is broken. Maybe use this URL instead: https://powerobjects.com/dynamics-365/html-web-resources-in-dynamics-365/